# Elasticsearch or Solr with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, solr

What is the best for making search for a client's website?. Normally I would go down the MySQL fulltext search route but I was feeling rather adventurous at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to keep an eye on this.

https://github.com/iverberk/larasearch

Still in it's infancy, but looks promising!